# Make an ajax call inside of a .map()

Tags: ajax, vue.js, async-await, array.prototype.map

I am upgrading jquery and saw that the "async: false" option has been deprecated. This makes sense and in 99.9% of cases I agree with the rationale, but I have a case where I think I really need it and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make this work with a purely async ajax call no matter how I use promises or async/await.

My use case is in a Vue component and I have an array of contacts. What I need to do is map over the contacts and validate them. One such validation requires a quick check of email validity via a "check_email" ajax endpoint.

Once I validate (or not) the list, I then submit the list (if valid) or show error messages (if invalid).

My code is something like this

```js
sendContacts: function() {
   valid = this.validateContacts()

   if (valid) {
       // send the contacts
   } else {
      return // will display error messages on contacts objects
   }
},

validateContacts: function() {
    this.contacts = this.contacts.map((contact) => {
          if (!contact.name) {
            contact.validDetails.name = false
            contact.valid = false
            return contact
          }
          if (!contact.email) {
            contact.validDetails.emailExists = false
            contact.valid = false
            return contact
          } 
          if (!check_email(email)) { // THIS IS ASYNC NOW WHAT DO I DO
            contact.valid = false
            contact.validDetails.emailFormat = false
          }
          return contact
    }
     var validData = this.contacts.map(c => {
          return c.valid
     })
     return !validData.includes(false)
}
```

```js
function check_email(email) {
  const url = `/api/v1/users/check-email?email=${email}`
  let valid = false
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    async: false, // I can't do this anymore
    headers: {
      'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken
    },
    success: resp => {
      valid = true
    },
    error: err => {
    }
  })
  return valid
}
```

my data function:

```
data: function() {
    return {
        contacts: [this.initContact()],
        showThanks: false,
        emailError: false,
        blankEmail: false,
        blankName: false
    }
  },
methods: {
    initContact: function() {
        return {
          name: null,
          email: null,
          title: null,
          validDetails: this.initValidDetails(),
          valid: true,
        }
    },
    initValidDetails: function() {
      return {
        emailDomain: true,
        emailExists: true,
        emailFormat: true,
        name: true
      }
    }
}
```

Again, I have tried async/await in every place I could think of and I cannot get this to validate properly and then perform correct logic regarding whether the send contacts function part of the function should fire. Please help!

Comment: Where is the async part? What is `check_email`? Is it a function that you call?

Comment: yeah, it's an ajax call that (used to) return a boolean - I'll add it to the question

Comment: What properties exist on each _contact_ before validation begins? Does the `valid` property exist? What about `validDetails` and the properties in that?

Comment: ok this might be messy haha butI will put the structure of the contacts in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once any part of your validation is asynchronous, you must treat the entire thing as asynchronous. This includes when calling `validateContacts` in `sendContacts`.

First, you should change `check_email` to return `Promise<bool>`. It's usually a bad idea to include jQuery in a Vue project so let's use `fetch` instead ([Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) being another popular alternative).

```js
async function check_email(email) {
  const params = new URLSearchParams({ email })
  const res = await fetch(`/api/v1/users/check-email?${params}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken
    }
  })
  return res.ok
}
```

As for your async validation logic, it's best to map your contacts to an array of promises and wait for them all with `Promise.all`.

```js
async validateContacts () {
  const validationPromises = this.contacts.map(async contact => {
    if (!contact.name) {
      return {
        ...contact,
        valid: false,
        validDetails: {
          ...contact.validDetails,
          name: false
        }
      }
    }
    if (!contact.email) {
      return {
        ...contact,
        valid: false,
        validDetails: {
          ...contact.validDetails,
          emailExists: false
        }
      }
    } 
    if (await check_email(contact.email)) { // await here
      return {
        ...contact,
        valid: false,
        validDetails: {
          ...contact.validDetails,
          emailFormat: false
        }
      }
    }
    return { ...contact, valid: true }
  })

  // now wait for all promises to resolve and check for any "false" values
  this.contacts = await Promise.all(validationPromises)
  return this.contacts.every(({ valid }) => valid)
}
```

---

As mentioned, now you need to treat this asynchronously in `sendContacts`

```js
async sendContacts () {
   if (await this.validateContacts()) {
     // send the contacts
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok so this looks really promising - THANK YOU but there's one more tangle as I am implementing. I need to mutate `this.contacts` to include that validation information so I can display error messages on the page. Using a new variable `validationPromises` doesn't get me that. Is there a way to do that here? Or do i just need to focus on validation and loop again if validation fails to add the appropriate validation 'fails'

Comment: So the objects are all defined, but the issue is that .map doesn't alter the original object, it returns a new array. I want to alter the original object, but .forEach, which I also tried doesn't return an array as it mutates the array in place. I can maybe get away with using the index to update the list in place, though - I am going to try that. Thank you so much for all of your help!

Comment: I did have to use the index to update `this.contacts` because it didn't mutate that array in a way that was reactive otherwise, but other than that - This works! THANK YOU

Comment: @AshleyH. I've updated the answer to look more like your original code where you produce a new array of altered contacts. You shouldn't need to use the index with this

Comment: Yes when I made that other comment about it still not working that was more or less my error. Thanks again, you've spent quite a bit of time with me on this tonight, I appreciate it!